# Jackson jaxrs xml provider upgrade issue - 2.4.1 to 2.5.0

Tags: java, xml, serialization, jackson, jax-rs

I am facing some issues while upgrading Jackson jaxrs xml provider from version 2.4.1 to 2.5.0. I am using the xml provider in Jersey (v1.19) based REST API project.

New version: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-xml-provider:2.5.0

Issue:
The custom serializers written to customize the default Jackson serialization are not getting invoked during serialization. These custom serializers were working with v2.4.1 and hence after the upgrade the API is not returning the desired output structure.

Please find my implementation of ContextResolver ans custom serializer below:

**XmlMapperContextResolver.java**

```
@Provider
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
public class XmlMapperContextResolver implements ContextResolver<XmlMapper> {
    private final XmlMapper animalXmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
    private final XmlMapper defaultXmlMapper = new XmlMapper();

    @Override
    public XmlMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
        if (Animal.class.isAssignableFrom(type)) {
            return animalXmlMapper;
        }
        return defaultXmlMapper;
    }

    public XmlMapperContextResolver() {
        JacksonXmlModule module = new JacksonXmlModule();
        module.setDefaultUseWrapper(false);

        // Adding Serializers
        module.addSerializer(CharacterMap.class, new CharacterMapSerializer());

        animalXmlMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);
        animalXmlMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
        animalXmlMapper.registerModule(module);


        defaultXmlMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);
        defaultXmlMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
    }
}
```

**CharacterMapSerializer.java**

```
public class CharacterMapSerializer extends
        JsonSerializer<Map<String, Character>> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Map<String, Character> value, JsonGenerator jgen,
            SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException,
            JsonProcessingException {

        provider.defaultSerializeField("Character", value.values(), jgen);
    }
}
```

**CharacterMap.java**

```
public class CharacterMap extends HashMap<String, Character> {    
}
```

During the execution `XmlMapperContextResolver` is invoked and it successfully returns an instance of animalXmlMapper. But while serializing the response, `CharacterMapSerializer` doesn't get called and instead Jackson applies its default serialization technique to build the XML response.

Comment: It would be best to create a stand-alone test case, outside of Jersey/JAX-RS first. This would allow figuring out if the problem is with JAX-RS provider (integration), or something within Jackson databind.

Comment: @dinup24 Did you figure this out?  I have a similar problem.